# Google Maps Javascript API: Multiple Markers at One Location Because of "Sub Stores"

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm building a site that uses this api to look for some specific stores. One of them is Target. The problem is my searches usually return 2 to 3 markers at the locations showing "Target", "Target Optics" and "Target Pharmacy". Does anyone know of a good way to have it show only the main "Target" marker?

Just as a reference here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var geocoder;
var map;
var service;
var infowindow;
var markers = new Array();
function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<?=$lat ?>, <?=$long ?>);
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    var request = {
        location: latlng,
        radius: '22000',
        types: ['store'],
        name: 'Target'
    };
    service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    service.search(request, callback);

}

function callback(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            var place=results[i];
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[i].geometry.location
            });
            markers[i] = marker;
            markers[i].reference = place.reference; 
        }
        //alert(markers.length);
    }
    for(j=0;j<markers.length;j++){
        google.maps.event.addListener(markers[j],'click',function(){
                var me = this;
                var request={reference:this.reference};
                service.getDetails(request,function(newplace,status){
                    var myContent = "<h3>" + newplace.name + "</h3>" + newplace.formatted_address;
                    infowindow.setContent(myContent);
                    infowindow.open(map,me);
                });
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessng you would hv to take a look at map clustering to get the job done. Here are some links that will help you achieve this:

http://www.appelsiini.net/2008/11/introduction-to-marker-clustering-with-google-maps or

http://www.svennerberg.com/2009/01/handling-large-amounts-of-markers-in-google-maps/

Both are client side clustering examples  though and I am guessing you would need server side clustering to group them together and give them the right name. You could probably right an algo to do the same.